# How do I get a random key from Json file so that I can display its value?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Working on an Android application, using KOTLIN. Inside my activity, I'm accessing the Merriam-Webster Dictionary JSON file from a URL (Github). The file's pretty big, to say the least. I want to display the "Word Of The Day" randomly on my TextView, which means I have to get a random key from the JSON so I can display its value.

**How do I do this?**

*Thank you in advance*

DictionaryActivity.kt

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary)
        fetchJson()
        init()
    }

    private fun init(){
        val email = intent.extras!!.getString("email", "")
        welcomeTxv.text = "Welcome, " + email.substringBefore("@")
    }

    // Fetching (url) and searching through json.
    private fun fetchJson(){
        println("Attempting to fetch Json file")

        val url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matthewreagan/WebstersEnglishDictionary/master/dictionary.json"

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                @Suppress("NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS") val jsonObject = JSONObject(body)
                loadingCircle.visibility = if (loadingCircle.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
                    View.INVISIBLE
                } else{
                    View.VISIBLE
                }

                searchBtn.setOnClickListener {
                    if (searchField.text.isNotEmpty() && jsonObject.has(searchField.text.toString())){
                        meaningTextView.setTextColor(WHITE)
                        meaningTextView.text = jsonObject.optString(searchField.text.toString())
                        databaseAction()
                    }else{
                        meaningTextView.setTextColor(RED)
                        meaningTextView.text = "The word you searched for could not be found."
                    }

                }


            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Request failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    fun databaseAction(){
        val email = intent.extras!!.getString("email", "")
        val userIdentification = email.toString()
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference(userIdentification.substringBefore("@"))
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance()
        val currentDate = sdf.format(Date())
        val stf = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance()
        val currentTime = stf.format(Date())
        myRef.push().setValue(searchField.text.toString() + " " + currentDate + " " + currentTime)
    }
```

This does not work (crashes the application):

```
val keys = arrayOf(jsonObject.keys())
                val randomNumber = (0..1000).random()
                val randomKey = keys[randomNumber]
```

Comment: If you're working with a huge file, don't load it all to memory. You can get an input stream response and use one of the json libraries to parse the stream. All you have to do is determine how much content you need to skip before taking the random word.

Comment: I mean, it loads pretty quickly. The dictionary works fast (EditText search) on slow devices as well. I wanna get a random key from the file to display its value (a string with an explanation of the word.)

Comment: What is the crash report from your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

application crashed because **index out of bound exception** throws...

```
 // keys() document from Android doc page
 open fun keys(): MutableIterator<String!>
```

keys() return type of **MutableIterator**

for more info: [Android JSON document link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/json/JSONObject#keys())

`keys` type is array of a MutableIterator, and its' length is 1
so, the expression below may throw index out of bound exception if randomNumber is not 0

```
val randomKey = keys[randomNumber] // opps if randomNumber is not zero
```

to get the random key from keys:

```
// shuffled() will return a list with random order
// first() take the first element of the list
val randomKey = xxxx.keys.shuffled().first()
```

no Android environment in my hand, here is my guess

```
val randomKey = jsonObject.keys().asSequence().toList().shuffled().first()
```

hope this gives you a little help :)